# MVC3 models throwing up null even though they're not part of the form. How to do "read only" model values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So in my view, I just want to be able to read the values provided by the Model.

```
@{
    var bgPath = "../Files/somedir/" + Model.FilePath;
}
```

So I can just dump it into a string to render an image to the DOM:

```
 <img id="bg-image" class="background-image" src="@bgPath" draggable ="false" alt="" />
```

Now, this works perfectly fine. My view renders properly. My problem is that when the form is submitted, it throws up **an error that Model.FilePath is null.**

The code is already OUTSIDE the main (and only) form field in the view.

I do not want to bind this data, I'm ONLY using it to give values to js. I have many other fields that seemed like they were going to work and there's not really the option of changing it without a load of rewrite.

So my question is, how to get read-only model values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to keep that in a hidden field in your form so that MVC model binding will make it available when submitting form.

```
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.FilePath)
   //other elements also 
   <input type="submite" />
}
```

But remember that, the hidden value field can be changed using browser extensions (like firebug) before posting. So If you are not updating the filepath by reading a new value from the user, do either one of this

1) Update only the relevant fields.  Have an Update method which updates only the relevant fields for the model.

```
 public bool UpdateCustomer(string name,string description,int id);
```

2) If updating all fields, Read from the domain object first and the update

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(YourViewModel model)
{
  var domainObject=repo.GetCustomerFromID (model.ID)
  //update only the relevant fields on loaded domain object
  domainObject.Description=model.Description;
  repo.SaveCustomer(domainObject);
  return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

Comment: This is unacceptable. are you telling me there's no way to just grab immutable values and render them to the page and not submit them in the postback (unbound) to MVC?

Comment: Now I'm going to have to go back and re-write like 10 dropdowns with a json request and build them dynamically. instead of foreach (var item in Model.Items)

Comment: Http is stateless and ASP.NET MVC stick to that truth. so you need to either post it or re read on submit

Comment: like what i mentioned in the 2nd approach. Read from the database and update only relevant fields. When you re read, you will have the file path value in your domain object (Assuming your repositary method returns that)

Comment: So setting the var domainObject to the repo is fine. Are you saying that if domainObject were also declared in the view that this would validate if I had var domainObject = (something from the model) in the view as well?

Comment: Don't mix domain object in the view. Use "View specific" viewmodels and map the values between them as needed in the controller action methods.

Comment: I guess that worked, but I had to re-write all my <select> items to query json and populate the lists because it would take to long to refactor each one to be bound to the model. So eventually for this image path value, I had JS pickup on the HiddenFor value... that seems like a long roundabout way to just get a read-only property into a view. So if I passed in a viewmodel into the main form I could just read the value and not worry about MVC trying to bind it?

Comment: Yes ok. I guess grabbing them from the viewbag is a better approach.